# Flex VideoDisplay Record/Save to disk/server

Tags: apache-flex, air, record

I have been searching and cannot find a solution yet.
I want to also add cuepoints to a live recording video as it is incoming.

I have a live feed incoming from a VideoDisplay object in my Flex Air app, and I would like to be able to record the video/audio of this and save it to disk and/or upload to server.

Is this possible? If so, would it be possible to add CuePoints to the video as it is being streamed live? Right now I am just trying to record a live stream from my VideoDisplay.

Any help is appreciated...

Thanks

-K

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [this cool utility class](http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/updated-flv-encoder-alchem/) that can encode FLV directly to disk from an Air application.  I think it does sound as well.  I'm not sure if it does CuePoints, but it's open source so you could always just add that functionality in :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the responses to this post. There are some solutions to try out. You will need a streaming server like Red5 or something else.

I will try and look for the code that adds cue points on the fly, have it somewhere.

[How do I record video to a local disk in AIR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113080/how-do-i-record-video-to-a-local-disk-in-air)

Also look at this post, which answers some of your questions:

http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/updated-flv-encoder-alchem/